# Вывод ответов из базы данных теста

Tags: php, mysql

Организовала вывод вопросов из базы данных, но не могу правильно написать запрос или функцию, чтобы ответы по айди вопроса подцеплялись к нему. Сейчас вопрос выводится 4 раза вместе с каждым ответом. Как это исправить?
Файл functions.php

```
function getquestions ($conn){
$sql="SELECT questions.question_id,questions.question,answers.answer from questions LEFT JOIN answers ON questions.question_id=answers.question_id";
$result=$conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows>0){
while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
$out[]=$row;
}
return $out;
}
}
```

Файл test.php

```
$data=getquestions($conn);
foreach ($data as $testItem)
{
echo $testItem['question_id']. '. ' . $testItem['question'];
echo '<br>';
echo $testItem['answer'];
echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: *Сейчас вопрос выводится 4 раза вместе с каждым ответом.* Это нормально. Более того - правильно при ПОЛУЧЕНИИ результата запроса. Иначе как определить, к какому вопросу относится тот или иной ответ? А вот при формировании ОТОБРАЖЕНИЯ результата Вы можете удалять эти "дубликаты".

Comment: @Akina я понимаю, что запрос получен правильно, и как раз не понимаю, как отобразить результат без дубликатов, не подскажете, как возможно это сделать?

Comment: Смотреть в сторону Group by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getquestions ($conn){
    $out = [];
    $sql="SELECT questions.question_id,questions.question,answers.answer from questions LEFT JOIN answers ON questions.question_id=answers.question_id";
    $result=$conn->query($sql);
    while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
        $out[$row['question_id']]['question'] = $row;
        $out[$row['question_id']]['answers'][] = $row;
    }

    return $out;
}
```

Файл test.php

```
$data = getquestions($conn);
foreach ($data as $testItem)
{
    echo $testItem['question']['question_id']. '. ' . $testItem['question']['question'];

    foreach ($testItem['answers'] as $answer)
    {
         echo '<br>';
         echo $answer['answer'];
         echo '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо!

Comment: Прошу прощения за глупый вопрос, а как можно оформить вывод ответа в виде radio button, чтобы name было id вопроса, а value id ответа?

Comment: @Лиза `echo '<label><input type="radio" name="question[' . $testItem['question']['question_id'] . ']" value="' . $answer['answer_id'] . '">' . $answer['answer'] . '</label>';`